# Is it possible to make an encrypted text look like a sentence consists of random words?

Tags: encryption

Without having any knowledge of common encryption methods, I wonder if an encrypted text can look like random valid words as if it is a sentence. Is it possible? If so, what methods should I use?

Comment: Might I ask why you want to do this?  If you're looking to do Stegangraphy, well, that's a lot harder than just generating text with valid English syntax.

Comment: It's like a combination of steganography and deniable encryption...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I simply don't want to encrypted text to look like one.

Comment: Both terms define what I want perfectly. Thanks @cygnusv

Comment: Most likely approach would be to create a "random sentence generator", then use encrypted data as the random numbers used to generate the sentences.  You'd need to make sure that at every step you can't generate the same word with different data (or, if you can, that you can distinguish it by looking at the following words).  An example might be those "fake scholarly paper generator" programs, e.g. [SCIgen](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/).

Comment: maybe [format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) does the job?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am not clear about this part: _" then use encrypted data as the random numbers used to generate the sentences."_ . Could you explain that part please?

Comment: A random sentence generator needs random data.  If, instead of generating random bytes, you pull the data out of the encrypted message, then the choices made can be reversed to find the encrypted text.  This would require some tweaking of the generator, so that it's always looking for a power-of-2 number of choices (and then pull that number of bits out of the encrypted message to make the choice, rather than using a RNG).

Comment: @StevePeltz: actually, there's no need to restrict yourself to power-of-2 number of choices.  It's certainly easier with the restriction; however the difficultly of handling the general case pales in comparison with the difficulty of the overall task.

Comment: Gotta learn more about this, in order to use that encryption I guess. Thank you @SOJPM